# Can charities be granted patents on medicine?

Tags: united-kingdom, patents

Can a charity patent a medicine that it invents?

Comment: You're asking an unremarkably high amount of questions. Keep them to the point, specific and clear, and most importantly, on-topic.

Comment: @Zizouz212 my questions are the best thing happened to this site, look how much attention they attract. I had 18 unread emails today. Clearly they're all of interest, real life stuff not academia

Comment: The dude, certainly, the community doesn't necessarily see it that way. The attention that is given is to the number of low-quality questions asked, and not necessarily the content. Emails? I never knew how that was relevant.

Comment: if they had no interest they wouldn't have read it. The fact they have negative reaction has to do with human's nature to shame others. Emails are the amount of feedback I receive.

Comment: @Thedude: You are mistaken.  Your questions are of poor quality.  They are attracting neither positive votes nor even significant view numbers.  Some number of active users review almost every post, especially by users like yourself with no reputation.  Do not mistake their attempts to salvage your contributions or encourage you to make meaningful ones for any measure of approval.  If your interest is in making positive contributions the metric to watch is upvotes.  If your intention is to be disruptive then please stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they meet the requirements for a patent including being a legal person, yes.